# How do you use spread() when your data has multiple "key" variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Edit: apologies for the more-than-minimal example. I redid this with a more parsimonious example, and it looks like aosmith's answer worked out!

This is the next step after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005763/looping-across-multiple-variables-and-parameters-using-map-and-mutate), in the same process. It's been a doozy.

I have a dataset with a series of variables, each with low, medium, and high values. There are also multiple identification variables, which here I am calling "scenario" and "month" just for this example. I'm doing a calculation involving 3 different values, some of which have a low, medium, or high value that varies in each scenario, and each month.

```
# generating a practice dataset

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)

pracdf <- bind_cols(expand.grid(ID = letters[1:2], 
                                month = 1:2, 
                                scenario = c("a", "b")),
                    data_frame(p.mid = runif(8, 100, 1000),
                               a = rep(runif(2), 4),
                               b = rep(runif(2), 4),
                               c = rep(runif(2), 4)))

pracdf <- pracdf %>% mutate(p.low = p.mid * 0.75,
                            p.high = p.mid * 1.25) %>%
  gather(p.low, p.mid, p.high, key = "ptype", value = "p") 

# all of that is just to generate the practice dataset.
# 2 IDs * 2 months * 2 scenarios * 3 different values of p = 24 total rows in this dataset

# Do the calculation

pracdf2 <- pracdf %>%
  mutate(result = p * a * b * c)
```

This fully "gathered" dataset has the results that I want. Let's do a spread-type operation to get this in a way that's a bit more readable, with each month, scenario, and p-type combination having it's own column. An example column name would be 'month1_scenario.a_p.low'. The total with this dataset would be 2 months * 3 p types * 2 scenarios  = 12 columns.

```
# this fully "gathered" dataset is exactly what I want. 
# Let's put it in a format that the supervisor for this project will be happy with
# ID, month, scenario, and p.type are all "key" variables
# spread() only allows one key variable at a time, so...

pracdf2.spread1 <- pracdf2 %>% spread(ptype, result, sep = ".")
# Produces NA's. Looks like it's messing up with the different values of p

pracdf2.spread2 <-  pracdf2 %>% select(-p) %>% spread(ptype, result, sep = ".")
# that's better, now let's spread across scenarios

pracdf2.spread2.spread2low <- pracdf2.spread2 %>% select(-ptype.p.high, -ptype.p.mid) %>% spread(scenario, ptype.p.low, sep = ".")
pracdf2.spread2.spread2mid <- pracdf2.spread2 %>% select(-ptype.p.low, -ptype.p.high) %>% spread(scenario, ptype.p.mid, sep = ".")
pracdf2.spread2.spread2high <- pracdf2.spread2 %>% select(-ptype.p.mid, -ptype.p.low) %>% spread(scenario, ptype.p.high, sep = ".")

pracdf2.spread2.spread2 <- pracdf2.spread2.spread2low %>% left_join(pracdf2.spread2.spread2mid)

# Ok, that was rough and will clearly spiral out of control quickly
# what am I still doing with my life?
```

I could do the spread() to spread each key column, then redo the spread for each consequent value column, but that will take ages and will likely be error-prone.

Is there a cleaner, tidier, and tidyr way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an incredibly over-complicated question to ask about "spread with multiple keys". Can you reduce this to a MWE that does not involve hundreds of rows and numerous other columns? You can probably get the same effect with 20 rows and 4 columns. (Said another way: I'd rather not parse through your full code to determine what is relevant to the question.) Examples: never `View`; repeated `spread`s; no idea why we need `left_join`. Busy/cluttered questions likely get less attention (IMO).

Comment: It might help if you cut your example down a bit to make it smaller and then show what the final result should look like.  If you want a column for each scenario/month/ptype (?) combination that is filled with "result" you can likely `unite` the three columns into one prior to spreading.

Comment: @aosmith, that did the trick, thanks! Could you post it as an answer so I can give you credit? (forgive me if there's a cleaner way to do this...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unite` from **tidyr** to combine the three columns into one prior to spreading.

Then you can `spread`, using the new column as the `key` and the "result" as `value`.

I also removed columns "a" through "p" prior to spreading, as it didn't seem like these were needed in the desired result.

```
pracdf2 %>%
     unite("allgroups", month, scenario, ptype) %>%
     select(-(a:p)) %>%
     spread(allgroups, result)

# A tibble: 2 x 13
  ID    `1_a_p.high` `1_a_p.low` `1_a_p.mid` `1_b_p.high` `1_b_p.low` `1_b_p.mid` `2_a_p.high` `2_a_p.low`
  <fct>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 a              160        96.2       128          423         254         338            209       126  
2 b              120        72.0        96.0         20.9        12.5        16.7          133        79.5
# ... with 4 more variables: `2_a_p.mid` <dbl>, `2_b_p.high` <dbl>, `2_b_p.low` <dbl>, `2_b_p.mid` <dbl>
```